# 502 Bad Gateway on POST/PUT Web API Calls from ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm getting strange errors in ASP.NET Core when calling Web API that I have created for the application. GET requests go through fine and return all of the data that they should, but my POST/PUT commands all return a 502, specifically from the MVC application. I can call the API's from Postman and get a proper response and the object is created in the database.

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while
>   acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server,
>   it received an invalid response from the content server.

I am impersonating an Integrated Windows Login with the following code for all web requests to the API:

```
async Task Action()
{
    response = await _service.CreateIncident(model);
}

await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, Action);
```

CreateIncident(model):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
        {
            var newIncident = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(hostUri, newIncident);
            return response;
        }
```

There is also one GET Request that I make through Ajax to get an incremented ID to display to the user before they create their new Incident that returns a 502 Bad Gateway as well. Is this an IIS Setting that is incorrect?

Comment: Is the newIncident string longer than 255 characters?

Comment: The command goes through to the server just fine (I didn't realize this was actually happening, I might have changed something to actually make this start working and not realized it...), but I'm still getting a 502 Bad Gateway error when I try to redirect the user after the PUT/POST request (E.g. user creates object, and then is directed to the GET page for that object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated and an asynchronous function, it will not work. You must be synchronous when doing non-GET requests. I have updated my GitHub issue, I'm hoping to get this bug addressed. If you are a future visitor to this topic, you can see where this ended up [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1954).

Answer (score 1):

I think it also depends on the size of the data. Smaller packages work, larger ones don't.